# Boot Windows 7 iso from grub2

Tags: grub2, windows, iso, bios

I want to do it because I want to install Windows 7 and my BIOS menu doesn't appear; it skips to grub2 menu at start, but that's another story... Is there a way to boot the Windows 7 installation iso directly from grub2?

Comment: " my BIOS menu doesn't appear" But have you tried to get into the BIOS?

Comment: What if i format the HDD? Will windows boot then? :)

Answer (score 8):

### Booting Windows XP with grub4dos

Booting the actual ISO with grub legacy or grub2 won't work, but with older windows versions (i.e. XP) it is possible to unpack the i386 folder from the ISO to the USB stick, and then use [grub4dos](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/) to call the bootloader:

```bash
title windows installer via setupldr.bin
find --set-root /i386/setupldr.bin
chainloader /i386/setupldr.bin
```

or

```bash
title windows installer via /bootsect.bin
find --set-root /i386/setupldr.bin
chainloader /bootsect.bin
```

This might not work with newer windows versions or with newer hardware but there is also the option of..

### Booting Windows 7 with grub2

With grub2 apparently something like this could work for **Windows 7**:

```bash
menuentry "Windows 7 (bootmgr)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    insmod ntldr
    ### A: either use this line or the next one, but not both
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)' 
    ### B: 
    ### search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid ____INSERT_PARTITION_UUID_HERE___
    ntldr ($root)/bootmgr
}
```

Option **A** assumes your bootable USB stick/HDD is the first device and has a msdos style partition table. Adjust to match your configuration. If your boot device has a GPT partition table, then most likely you'll need to use `(hd0,gpt1)` (GPT in general is trickier to set up).

Option **B** uses the drive's unique UUID, which can be seen on Linux with `sudo blkid` or on OSX with e.g. `diskutil info disk0s1` (or Disk Utility > Info).

The final entry might look for example like this:

```bash
menuentry "Windows 7 installer" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    insmod ntldr
    search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 0E239BC6-F960-3107-89CF-1C97F78BB46B
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

Comment: Nice. I did use --set=root --fs-uuid UUIDHERE (changed order) instead, though (couldn't say whether it was required or not). Thanks

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik Could you boot from ISO?

Comment: That is my recollection, yes. I wouldn't have been interested in the other stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, you'd think something like this would work:

```
menuentry "Boot Windoze" {
  search -f "--set-root /Winblows.iso"
  drivemap "/Winblows.iso" '(hd32)'
  drivemap '--hook' ''
  set root='(hd32)'
  chainloader +1
}
```

But Windows will just balk at that.

If you happen to have at least 4GB RAM, you can opt to load the whole DVD iso in [memdisk](http://www.syslinux.org/memdisk.php) and boot off that. To do that, [download](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Download) SysLinux and extract the `memdisk` file into your `boot` directory. Then you need to add code to Grub2 something like this

```
menuentry "Boot Windoze" {
  search -f "--set-root /Winblows.iso"
  insmod memdisk
  linux16 /boot/memdisk iso
  initrd16 /Winblows.iso
}
```

However, I'm not going to even test the code, as putting 3+ GB of data into RAM is just plain wrong (from an idealogical standpoint). No, I really wanted what you want, but in the end I put the Windows install on a partition on a USB using [the Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) and chainloaded to that. Sorry there doesn't seem to be any other way that I can see.

Comment: First code will boot windows but fail after sometime as windows don't know where the iso is mounted

Comment: Second code may not work, as it will not work with iso of Ubuntu

Comment: The OP is referring specifically to Windows 7. Been able to test that?

Comment: You may not like Windows, but posting "Winblows" and "Windoze" here is rather unprofessional. -1.

Comment: As I'm not a professional bootstrap programmer, I can live with "unprofessional". I think you might have meant "disrespectful". Yeah, that comment was 6 years ago. I have changed a lot since then (and so has Windows)

Comment: tell from linux16 command I think memdisk [does not work in UEFI] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690607/77353) We really need an UEFI memdisk :D

Answer (score 6):

Technically installing from windows's `.iso` file can't be possible. You can boot from the `.iso` using grub but after that Windows will loss contact with the mounted location or it is not capable of it. So both `grub` & Windows should aware of mount and boot. Currently Windows doesn't support.

So you need to extract/copy the content of `.iso` to root of a partition and then chain-load into it using `grub`.

Comment: good idea to share knowledge, but you could add directly answering the question in technical manner. namely reuse the current text as a disclaimer but then you could expand the "you can boot from the .iso" into menuentries or something. that way you'd make exact which method(s) you imagined to achieve what was asked, although which you know not to work for the assumed purpose. this would also disambiguate the count of solutions that you did consider.

Answer (score 0):

you can make ntfs partition or format usb drive to ntfs, extract windows 7/8/10/11 iso to this partition or usb drive, make sure that all of files extracted,`sudo update-grub` and reboot to see spacefic windows boot menu entry which you can use to install windows.

you can install grub2 on usb drive and [make multiboot USB by Ubuntu without any especial tool to install ubuntu and windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474717/create-usb-drive-contains-multi-ubuntu-versions-hbcd-pe-64-and-multi-windows-in).