# Can I download windows 10 on Ubuntu 22.04 without a usb or cd?

Tags: windows

So basically I lost my windows 10 usb and I can't afford to buy a new one. I need windows because most of the programs I run are on windows. Somebody please help

Comment: You can download the Windows ISO file from their official website using Ubuntu. But you will need an USB you won't be able to install it on your computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Comment: in case you need it: this will show your serial key `sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM`

Answer (score 0):

### Install windows from hard disk

1- download windows 7/8/10/11 iso file.

2- extract the iso file to `ntfs` data partition.

3- `sudo update-grub` or add a menu entry to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

```
menuentry "Windows installation Environment" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  55DD0595418E5BFC
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 55DD0595418E5BFC
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
```

Replace `55DD0595418E5BFC` by the uuid for that partition which given from disk utitity.

Replace 0 and 1 in the entry by yours, 0 is the hard no. and 1 is the partition no.


Related: [create-usb-drive-contains-multi-ubuntu-versions-hbcd-pe-64-and-multi-windows-in-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474717/create-usb-drive-contains-multi-ubuntu-versions-hbcd-pe-64-and-multi-windows-in)


***note***: install windows will delete grub boot loader frome your hard disk so if you want to back to ubuntu you will have to use boot-repair or ubuntu live USB to restore grub boot loader and add Windows entrys to grub menu so no need to windows boot loader again.