supergrub2 boot iso : error: out of range
In attempt to boot ISO from SuperGrub2 Ubuntu-derivatives will fail to load the vmlinuz or initrd.lz from casper. All files are accessible on grub but fail to load on memory.
I have used the following command on SuperGrub shell
set isofile=/User/<userprofile>/Downloads/ubuntu.iso
loopback loop (hd0,gpt3)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile

And immediately the shell throw this error:
error: out of range
you need to load kernel first


Sorry I am not seeing how this is related to the Ubuntu OS.

Path does not look correct. When booting directly with grub loopmount, no partitions are mounted by Ubuntu. So you have to look at drive as if from live installer. Or use 'ls` at grub> to find correctly path.

I used grml-rescueboot to generate a menu entry and I modified it based on the ISO file place in my hard disk:
# super_grub2_disk

    menuentry "super_grub2_disk" --class recovery{
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ntfs
            set root='hd0,msdos3'
            iso_path="/super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.04s1.iso"
            export iso_path
            kernelopts="   "
            export kernelopts
            # support booting recent GRUB versions on UEFI systems
            rmmod tpm
            loopback loop "/super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.04s1.iso"
            set root=(loop)
            configfile /boot/grub/loopback.cfg
    }

If you want to add Ubuntu 23 or 24 ISO file, use like this menu entry:
menuentry "Try or Install ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64" {
     
loopback loop /ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper layerfs-path=minimal.standard.live.squashfs iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso quiet splash locale=en_US bootkbd=us console-setup/layoutcode=us noeject --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}

You can see some menu entries related to ISO files in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1474729/1698042
