Grub Rescue error on fresh bootable drive
I made a fresh bootable drive by using the following command:
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo dd bs=4M if=ubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sda1 status=progress conv=fsync

and when I tried installing Ubuntu on my PC, I got a Grub Rescue error.
I faced this error earlier on the same PC when I was trying to install One of Ubuntu Flavors so decided to fix this by Rufus as earlier it was a Windows system, where it popped up with a warning message that there is some issue with the version of Grub that is being there in the iso file that I downloaded from the official site.
So I checked with the latest version of Ubuntu 22.04 whose code is mentioned above and suspect it has the same issue.
Kindly guide me on how to resolve this issue.

Here is the official Ubuntu install tutorial. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1474718/1698042

For Ubuntu 22.04, use an old version of Rufus. The new version of Rufus is based on Grub 2.12, while Ubuntu 22.04 is based on Grub 2.06.

I'm looking for ways to make a bootable pen drive via the command line. Also, Is there a way to know the grub version's compatibility with the files in the iso file?
